# How to get my function to execute on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple function to loop thought a bunch of Divs fading them in and out. It works fine, but I'm trying to make the function also execute when a DIV is clicked.

I thought if I do something like

```
$('.content').click(InfiniteRotator());
```

or

```
$('.content').click(function(){
InfiniteRotator();
});
```

But no luck and suggestion would be most appreciated

```
$(window).load(function() {

    function InfiniteRotator() {

        //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
        var initialFadeIn = 1000;

        //interval between items (in milliseconds)
        var itemInterval = 5000;

        //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
        var fadeTime = 1000;

        //count number of items
        var numberOfItems = $('.quote').length;

        //set current item
        var currentItem = 0;

        //show first item
        $('.quote').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(initialFadeIn);

        //loop through the items
        var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function(){
         $('.quote').eq(currentItem).fadeOut(fadeTime);

            if(currentItem == numberOfItems -1){
                 currentItem = 0;
            } else{
                 currentItem++;
            }

            $('.quote').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime);

        }, itemInterval);
    }

    InfiniteRotator();


    $('.content').click(InfiniteRotator());


});
```

Comment: `$('.content').click(InfiniteRotator);` Use referenced function as handler, not returned value which here is undefined. But your second try must work, using anonymous function. Beware, your function won't be available in global scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass the `reference` of that function like,

```
$('.content').click(InfiniteRotator);
```

And by the way, as others mentioned there's no problem with the following code of yours,

```
$('.content').click(function(){
   InfiniteRotator();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.content').click(InfiniteRotator); //<----remove the "()" here
```

or

```
$('.content').click(function(){
    InfiniteRotator();
});
```

Both are fine this way now but you have to call it in doc ready wrapper and you can move your function in the global scope outside of doc ready:

```
function InfiniteRotator() {
   // your function
}

$(function(){
   $('.content').click(InfiniteRotator); //<---here you can call it
});
```

You are better to use `$(function(){})` doc ready handler instead of `$(window).load()` because this does not wait for dom to fully loaded.

Comment: OP is already using window onload handler. That's said, it's more legitimate to use document ready handler as you suggest it